# Javascript scroll-to function, how to detect height of header with javascript?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, header

I have a somewhat simple problem that I cant seem to figure out. I am a little new to javascript.

I am making a single page website with a fixed header. My navigation is powered by javascript function that scrolls to linked divs and offsets the top by 80px (the height of my header) and it works perfectly.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){

        var el = $(this).attr('href');
        var elWrapped = $(el);

        scrollToDiv(elWrapped,40);

        return false;

    });

    function scrollToDiv(element,navheight){
        var offset = element.offset();
        var offsetTop = offset.top;
        var totalScroll = offsetTop - 80 + "px";

        $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: totalScroll
        }, 500);

    }



});
```

My issue is that when my website is loaded on mobile my header grows to about 215px (I am using skeleton framework), and the scroll to function still scrolls the 80px. How can I use javascript dynamically detect the height of the header and insert it into this scroll to function rather then using a fixed height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$("#header").outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) will return the total height of the #header element.

Comment: I am actually using html5 for the header so it is just "header". How would I implement it into the code.I used your suggestion but now my scroll animation doesn't work.

Comment: For a <header> tag, it would be $("header").outerHeight() . Does that work?

Comment: I tried that, I think I may be putting it in the wrong place. Can you give me an example of where to put it

Comment: It should go in place of the "80", like this:


var totalScroll = offsetTop - $("header").outerHeight() + "px";

I have it working in a small test script so if this doesn't work the problem might be somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did and the scroll animation doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can you open the Javascript console and see if any errors pop up when you click a nav link?

Comment: TypeError: $("header").outerHeight is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var totalScroll = offsetTop - $("header").outerHeight() + "px";

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am an idiot, it was an older version, I didn't even check that. It is working now, thank you very much, I would have never thought of that.